# ¿Cómo crear un lista con valores de coordenadas?

Tags: python, lista, bucles

Tengo un diccionario y dentro tengo k:id y v: un monton de cosas entre ellas unas coordenadas. longitud = mensaje['Long'] y latitud = mensaje['Lat'] y quiero guardarlos en una lista que contenga [lon,lat], y poder decir coord[15] y que me de una Lon y una Lat, pero no consigo hacerlo.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```
for id,mensaje in aismsg.items():
    coord = []
    coord.append([mensaje['Lon'],mensaje['Lat']])
```

pero si ahora hago, por ejemplo

```
coord[3]
```

me da error de:

> IndexError: list index out of range

Cuando en realidad deberia haber muchos valores.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español. Acá te dejo un par de guías sobre cómo realizar preguntas en el sitio: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Tu pregunta podría mejorar mucho.

Comment: Si quieres que te ayudamos un poco mejor, deberías poner una muestra de la estructura del diccionario en cuestión, así es muy a ciegas. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en esta línea:

```
coord = []
```

Aquí, estas asignando a la variable `coord` una lista vacía. Esto es un paso necesario, para posteriormente introducir elementos a dicha lista. El problema viene cuando tanto esta inicialización como la asignación de nuevos elementos lo haces dentro del mismo bucle `for`.

- En la primera iteración: creas una lista vacía y añades un par de longitudes y latitudes.
- En la segunda iteración: **vuelves** a crear una lista vacía, todo el contenido anterior que había en la variable `coord` se pierde, pues le estás asignado una lista vacía nueva.

Al final de la ejecución del bucle, vas a tener que `coord` es una lista que solo contiene un elemento, por lo que no puedes acceder al cuarto elemento por ejemplo.

Para solucionar esta situación, solo necesites crear la lista, antes del bucle `for`:

```
coord = [] # => Crear una lista vacía solo una vez
for id,mensaje in aismsg.items():
    coord.append([mensaje['Lon'],mensaje['Lat']])
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Las respuesta de Madh es correcta. Esto solo para "evangelizar" sobre el uso de la "comprensión de listas", este código hace lo mismo de manera más compacta:

```
coord = [[v['Lon'],v['Lat']] for k, v in aismsg.items()]
```